# WebGL does not work properly on Raspberry Pi Chromium Browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, webgl, chromium

I have a problem with WebGL on Raspberry Pi 3's Chromium browser. I did the settings required but nothing happened.

Here is my information

- **Device :** Raspberry Pi 3
- **OS :** Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux(Raspian Stretch with desktop, i also try lite)
- **Browser :** chromium-browser version => Chromium 60.0.3112.89 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 9.3
- **Graphics Driver :** vc4-kms-v3d

Here are the get.webgl.org results:

[image: get.webgl.org results]

Here is the threejs.org example ("webgl_animation_cloth") results:

[image: threejs.org example "webgl_animation_cloth" results]

I tested the same websites on firefox iceweasel.
They work as shown by these screenshots:

[image: get.webgl.org results(iceweasel)]

[image: threejs.org example "webgl_animation_cloth" results(iceweasel)]

I tried several settings on chrome://flags but nothing is changed

**Edit** : when i use the command line to open chromium, the chromium opened but gives this error;

**libgl error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information**

Comment: Have you tried checking https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Yes, i cannot found something usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My same question is anwered at raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, i try it and it works,

After the enable KMS from `raspi-config`, remove "--disable-gpu-compositing'' from /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-rpi-var

Thanks to @joeyck